# Simple solution to extract PDF.zip using PHP

Tags: php, unzip, 7zip

I have a rather large zip file (I used 7zip to compress the files) and I must now extract the files that are on the server. I tried using CPANEL File Manager but the zip file is too big.

Any ideas on how I can extract this zip file?

I do not have SHELL ACCESS and would prefer to use a software tool, if there is one out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try, maybe this works. You can also use exec function

```
<?php
$salida = shell_exec('unzip you.zip');
echo $salida;
```

Comment: I can't run the sell_exec function because I don't have safe_mode enabled

Comment: Insert this line into your .htaccess file: php_admin_flag safe_mode On